# Generating a File from a template based on a value from typescript or file like json

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, spfx, file-conversion

I have a SPFX webpart that takes in user data then sends the data to a list [this is how the list looks for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWw6.png) and all the values are stored like this:

```
export interface SPListItem
{
   localIndex: number;
   ID: number;
   Title: String;
   CompanyName: string;
   ClientName: string;
   CurrentDate: string;
   PreferredDate: string;
   RequestedBy: string;
   TypeOf: string;
   Reason: string;
   Urgent: string;
   Department: string;
   Chargeable: string;
   EstimatedTime: string;
   approvedStatus: string;
}
```

in the main webpart class:

```
private getListItemData(): void
{
    this._getListData()
        .then( ( response ) =>
    {
        let index: number = 0;
        response.value.forEach( ( item: SPListItem ) =>
        {
                this.listItems[ index ] = 
                {
                    localIndex: 0,
            Title: item.CompanyName + "-" + item.RequestedBy,
            CurrentDate: item.CurrentDate,          
                    Chargeable: item.Chargeable,
            ID: item.ID,

            CompanyName: item.CompanyName,
            ClientName: item.ClientName,
            RequestedBy: item.RequestedBy,
            PreferredDate: item.PreferredDate,
            Department: item.Department,
            TypeOf: item.TypeOf,
            Urgent: item.Urgent,
            EstimatedTime: item.EstimatedTime,
            Reason: item.Reason,
            approvedStatus: item.approvedStatus,
                };
        
                index++;
        } );
        this.printListItemInfo();
        return;
    } )
    .catch( ( err ) =>
    {
        throw Error( err );
    } );
}
```

I am looking for a way to get this data into a premade file. (so have a docx template for example, copy the template and replace all the place holders in the template with the values)

I have been researching ways for a week and the closest method I found was using https://docxtemplater.com/ as it says and with https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#update-file-content but after a lot of frustration I believe it wont work in my situation.

At the moment I have the values exporting to a json file:

newGen.json:

```json
{
    "Company Name"   : "a",
    "Client Name"    : "b",
    "Current Date"   : "c",
    "Preferred Date" : "d",
    "Requested By"   : "e",
    "Type"           : "f",
    "Reason"         : "g",
    "Urgent"         : "h",
    "Department"     : "i",
    "Chargeable"     : "j",
    "Estimated Time" : "k"
}
```

(Note: I also made a html file export but had a similar issue converting that into pdf or docx without just manually doing it which would defeat the purpose)

Comment: Is thins http server, nodejs script, web page, or what? What do you want to achieve? Why didn't provided lin work?

Comment: its a sharepoint framework webpart, 
I want to get the data received as shown above and apply it to a file template,
It didnt work using the links provided as that uses node only libs such as fs and pnpjs is not a valid replacement for fs or path @Dimava